# Add scale to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I'd like to add a scale to help in the understanding of my ggplot.
In order to simplify, the reproductible data set is part of my original dataset

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- tribble( ~ compound, ~group,~matrix, ~min_measure, 
                ~max_measure, ~ref,
                "BC","Environnement","water", 0.1, 2120,"1",
                "BC","Fruit","apple", 0.001, 9.8,"2",
                "BC","Cereals","rice", 0.1, 47.6,"3",
                "IS","Vegetable","Salad", 0.1, 331.7,"4",
                "TL","Environnement","soil" ,3.2*1000, 
                9.3*1000,"5",
                "TL","Environnement","water" , 0.02*1000, 
                1.22*1000,"6",
                "FD","Environnement","soil" , 1.6, 10,"7")
df1_b <- df1 %>% group_by(compound, group, matrix) %>% 
  summarize(min=min(min_measure, na.rm = TRUE), 
            max=max(max_measure))

ggplot(df1_b, aes(xmin=min, xmax=max, y=matrix)) + 
  geom_linerange(size=1.5) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) +
  scale_x_log10("ng/g", breaks=c(1e-3, 1, 1000)) +
  facet_grid(compound ~., scales="free", space="free", 
             switch="y") +
  theme_classic() + theme(strip.placement="outside", 
                          strip.text.y.left=element_text(angle=0))
```

What I got with my code:

[image: Plot I got]

What I would like is something like that (realised without R)

[image: plot final]

I tried to add new plot under my first ggplot but I did not find a way to align other plot at a specified x value of my first plot.

Does anyone know a way to add multi-scale under a ggplot or to do something quite similar to my dream final plot ?

Comment: is this about adding logarithmic scales? Why don't you integrate those scales into the x scale? You could use the ggh4x package https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/reference/guide_axis_logticks.html The ggh4x package also has some wicked nested facet options.

Comment: However, if you really need those three (IMO confusing) scales - maybe just create them as an extra plot and add with e.g. patchwork

Comment: @tjebo thanks for your advice, I really need the three scales, I checked already patchwork. I should probably look more carefully as I was not able to align the "1st scale" to the x=1 from my ggplot